# password special char ! in wsadmin script

Tags: python, shell, websphere, jython, wsadmin

I have a python/jython script to automate web sphere console.

I am trying to create JAASAuth using the script and the password is test123!

my script is as given below

```
./wsadmin.sh -username wasadmin -password wasadmin -lang jython -c "print AdminTask.createAuthDataEntry('[-alias ALIAS -user tstusr -password test123! -description Authentication ]');"
```

script finishes well. But the DataSource connection test fails as the password for Auth is incorrect. Missing the special char !. When I manually update the passoword in WAS console, it works well.

I tried single quotes ' ' and escape characters and no luck.

Would be great if anyone can share some info on this. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried putting that command into a .py file and running that? The problem might actually just be the Unix shell interpreting the exclamation point.

Comment: I tried runnign like this.. still no luck

./wsadmin.sh -username user -password pass -lang jython -c "print AdminTask.createAuthDataEntry('[-alias AUTH -user tstusr -password "'tst123\!'" -description Authentication ]');"

Comment: Are you using bash?  Bash does not strip out the `\ ` before the exclamation mark - it is a weird side-effect of command recall.  Can you use a different shell to launch it?  If you `echo "'tst123\!'"` with and without the `\ ` you will see what I mean.

Comment: Try the password with just single quotes around it:  `'tst123!'`

Comment: First, I still say you want to prove whether this is a shell thing or a wsadmin/jython thing. (And I think it's a shell thing.) You'd do that by putting that command into a `createAuth.py` file and running wsadmin with `-f createAuth.py`

Comment: Thanks Guys, the original command itself was working. I had to restart the application server to test the data source connectivity. Password is being encrypted and stored in the resources.xml. Password field in the console shows only 7 dots regardless of the actual password supplied through script. Mystery resolved. Appreciate your help on this folks.